# Don't show contentblockById using Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I use the following AMP to decide which contentblock I want to show.

```
%%[

    /* UTM code genereren */
    SET @Huidig_Pakket  = AttributeValue("Huidig_Pakket")
        
    /* Kies en koop */
    ELSEIF @Huidig_Pakket == "Kies & Koop"           THEN
        SET @Pakketblok                 = 429704
        SET @Pakketblok_01              = 429737
        SET @Pakketblok_02              = 429737
        SET @Pakketblok_03              = 430259

    /* Geld en Recht */
    ELSEIF @Huidig_Pakket == "Geld & Recht"          THEN
        SET @Pakketblok                 = 429704
        SET @Pakketblok_01              = 429737
        SET @Pakketblok_02              = 429737
        SET @Pakketblok_03              = 430259
        
    ENDIF
    ]%%
```

In the email I use code below to show the content piece.

```
%%=BeginImpressionRegion("Pakketblok_03")=%% %%=ContentBlockById(@Pakketblok_03)=%% %%=EndImpressionRegion("Pakketblok_03")=%%
```

But for some categories (these are only a few examples, the original version is more extended) I don't want to show a thing. So it must not show the contentblock. I tried SET @Pakketblok_03              = NULL , but it doesn't work, does anybody know how this works?

Comment: BeginImpressionRegion doesn’t display anything, it’s just for reporting. Can you clarify what exactly needs to happen and under what conditions?

Comment: The AMP works perfectly if I fill in all the codes (`SET @Pakketblok_03              = 430259`), but this is only partly the script. For some I want to empty the block (`SET @Pakketblok_03              =`), but then I get an error. So how can I show at some places a `@Pakketblok_03` and at some I don't.

Comment: You need to add the full script for us to be able to help you with that

Comment: I found a solution! I added a HTML block with only a comment in there, so it won't show anything in the email. The ID of that contentblock I used for the parts that I don't want to show any block.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution! I added a HTML block with only a comment in there, so it won't show anything in the email. The ID of that contentblock I used for the parts that I don't want to show any block.